# Kohler bathtub cold water stem removal

Tags: faucet, bathtub

Need to remove stem from bathtub cold water faucet which turns on clockwise and off counter-clockwise. Does Lefty-Loosy apply here?

Answer (score -1):

98 out of 100 times it is indeed lefty loosey. In cases of some power tools it is the opposite.

Comment: Did some one use gas fittings they hav a slot on the nut and are reverse threads with thumb at 12 o'clock turning right is CW to the left is CCW . I have had a very blond firend that did not understand this until I showed her how the faucet worked,,, P.S. We are married and I still tease her now that the blond is gray.